# How to set an Attribute to Array for AttributeToJSON Processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

*NiFi Version 1.8.0*

I'm trying to build our my json, and one of my fields needs to be an array. I thought I could simply use the UpdateAttribute Processor to set my attribute to '["arrayItem1", "arrayItem2"]' and then I could used AttributeToJSON to convert the attribute to JSON and it would convert to an array. Unfortunately, it simply turns into a string.

In the simplest way, how can I set an attribute to be an array so my final JSON (when using AttributeToJSON) field has the specific array?

**EDIT 1**

I will have a few SyslogListeners, I want to set an attribute so I know what data came from where. I want to be able to tag this data, so I though of adding an UpdateAttribute to set my attribute. I would like this to be an array. So the tag for:

SyslogListener1 will be ["tag1", "tag2"]

SyslogListener2 will be ["tag3", "tag4"]

SyslogListener3 will be ["tag1", "tag3"]

I thought of just having my flow look like this: [SyslogListener](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenSyslog/) -> [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html) -> Then all the data is now in the main flow -> [AttributeToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/). However, when I look at my JSON, my field is a string, not an array. How can I make this field to be an array? What I used to do, was use [ReplaceText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/) , the only problem with this is I didn't want to create a ReplaceText for ever single instance. Is there a single processor that could handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my ideal solution, but I simply added a ReplaceText for each instance I would need. In my case, it was 7 different tag formations. So my nifi looks a little ugly. I was hoping for a single processor solution where I could tell it my JSON field and make it an array. So my pipeline is:

SyslogListener **->** UpdateAttribute (creates our **tags** attribute with the string *tag1, tag2* and the other tag combinations because I have 7 total SyslogListeners with their own UpdateAttribute) **->** Data is now in the main pipeline, and some Other processing stuff happens here **->** AttributeToJSON (setting our json with some attributes including our **tags** attribute) **->** My 7 ReplaceTexts (which checks to see if our tags field has *"tag1, tag2"* and then replaces it with *["tag1", "tag2"]*, I do this for all 7 cases) **->** PutElasticSearchHttp

So ingesting rsyslog messages, doing a bit of enriching, making my data into a JSON, then saving it to ES.

If anyone knows a single processor solution to this, so I don't need to have 7 unique ReplaceTexts (and more if I need new tags).

Answer (score 0):

Does your incoming flow file have any existing content? If not, you can use `ReplaceContent` to set the content to `["arrayItem1", "arrayItem2"]` or whatever you wish the JSON to look like.

If the incoming flow file has existing JSON content, you can add the field explicitly (without attributes) using `JoltTransformJSON` or `UpdateRecord`.

Comment: It doesn't have any existing. Basically, I have a few different SyslogListeners, and the first Processor I'm using is UpdateAttribute because I want to tag this data coming in to handle later. So 1 might look like ["array1", "array2"], but another would be ["array2", "array3"]. The attribute name is the same, so AttributeToJSON works perfect for me. But as I said, it just turns it into a string, not a real array. What is ReplaceContent? I only see ReplaceText. Note, I previously used Replace Text, but is it possible to have a single processor handle this, or would I need multiple ReplaceTexts?

Comment: See my new **Edit** I added in my question.

Comment: AttributesToJson will replace the content with the attributes (and will keep the array as a string). Are you trying to add the array as a field in your existing JSON? Also do you know how many tags you'll have (i.e. will there always be two elements in the array)?

Comment: No, there is no existing JSON. I'm ingesting rsyslog/syslog messages. My end goal is to send these messages to an Elastic Cluster, but before I send it their, I want to tag the data (a single message could have 1 to 3 tags associated). This is why I was adding an UpdateAttribute to add a new attribute with my tags. Then, I want to use AttributeToJSON so prepare to put my data in Elastic. The only issue is I can't seem to create my JSON so the "tags" field is an array. Again, this is from scratch, nothings exists. I'm new to NiFi and still learning.

Comment: What about doing AttributesToJson before you add the tags, then add them via JoltTransformJson or UpdateRecord?

Comment: So I'm just now getting involved with UpdateRecord, but have no idea how to use it properly. I'm currently learning how to use it for Grok patterns. How could I use UpdateRecord in my case to convert a JSON field that is currently a string into an array? Or are you thinking of another way?

Comment: If you have a field in the content that is a string but you want to convert it to a JSON object, you may be left with a scripted solution like ExecuteScript or InvokeScriptedProcessor; Groovy has built-in support for converting strings to GOJOs and GOJOs to JSON (see JsonSlurper and JsonOutput for more details)